# cannot able to capture screenshot of layout file in android

Tags: java, android

Here is my android application code where what I need is when I click on floating button then it will automatically took screenshot and store it but when I click on button then my application will crash.

`sample.java`

```
package com.example.certificate;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sample);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Bitmap screenshot = captureScreenshot();

                try {
                    // Save the bitmap to a file
                    String fileName = "screenshot.png";
                    File screenshotFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(screenshotFile);
                    screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "Screenshot saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "Failed to save screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
//                getScreen();

                Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    private Bitmap captureScreenshot() {
        // Inflate the layout file
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, null);

        // Create a bitmap with the same dimensions as the view
        Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Create a canvas with the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
        view.draw(canvas);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Capture Screenshots", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return screenshot;
    }

    public static void saveScreenshot(Context context, View view, String filename) {
        // Get the size of the view
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Create a canvas to draw the view onto the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // Draw the view onto the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);

        // Save the bitmap to a file
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

`activity_sample.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Sample"
        android:id="@+id/lid">
        <include layout="@layout/certificateui" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

`certificateui.xml`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E91E63">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="138dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="429dp"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text="Rahul Raj "
            android:textSize="48sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="On Completed Level 3"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="+919825296591"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Congratulations"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="92dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:text="Near Sanskar Deep school, Lajamani Chowk, Surat.-394101"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"

            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.994"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="377dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />


    <!-- Your other layout views -->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`drawable/bottom_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E5FCFB"/>
            <corners  android:radius="50dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Certificate"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">


        <activity
            android:name=".Sample"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_certificate"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is how application looks like :

[image]

When I try to run it then it will crash automatically even if I gave permission for accessing file then also it will not able to save screenshot